# next build Export encountered errors on following paths: / /_error: /404 /_error: /500

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have create a new next.js project with this command

```
npx create-next-app@latest myapptest
```

it is running fine. but when I try to create a static site it give. me error like this.

```
Linting and checking validity of types    
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.3

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build    
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Collecting page data    
   Generating static pages (0/3)  [=   ]TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at g (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/_error.js:1:5481)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at g (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/_error.js:1:5481)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at g (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/_error.js:1:5481)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at g (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/_error.js:1:5481)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at m (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/index.js:1:13689)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at exports.useContext (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at m (/Users/apple/repos/backend/xenovassoft/.next/server/pages/index.js:1:13689)
    at Wc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at bd (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:77:404)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:217)
    at Zc (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:479)
    at Z (/Users/apple/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
 ✓ Generating static pages (3/3) 

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    /_error: /404
    /_error: /500
```